# style-loader with typings-for-css-modules-loader using webpack

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-style-loader

I want to use style-loader to load scss to my TypeScript React components using webpack. When working with only css, I have the following set of rules:

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader" },
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader?modules&namedExport" }
```

and it works as expected.

But when I try using sass (following the guide available on the package page), it turns into:

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader" },
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader?modules&namedExport" },
{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader?modules&namedExport&sass" },
```

And that doesn't work, as I don't see any style tags in the result.

Am I missing something or not really understanding how this works?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following two modifications allows loading sass modules. The first is changing the `style-loader` test to also include scss files. The second is adding `sass-loader` as the initial loader for scss files. You will likely need to install the sass-loader package. So the rules would now be:

```
{ test: /\.(css|scss)$/, loader: "style-loader" },
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader?modules&namedExport" },
{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader?modules&namedExport&sass" },
{ test: /\.scss$/, loader: "sass-loader" }
```